# Deep linking with react-native-quick-actions is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, quickaction

I am trying to implement quick actions in my react native app.

**lets say:**

There are 3 shortcut items. When long pressed in app icon, it will show these menus but when tapped those, it just opens app, but deep linking is not working.

But whenever I enter those urls in safari, deep linking works. (app does open and navigate to mentioned screen)

```
QuickActions.setShortcutItems([
            {
                type: "Camera", 
                title: "Camera", 
                subtitle: "",
                icon: "Camera", 
                userInfo: {
                    url: "app://camera"
                }
            },
            {
                type: "Profile", 
                title: "Profile", 
                subtitle: "",
                icon: "Contact", 
                userInfo: {
                    url: "app://profile"
                }
            },
            {
                type: "Change Password", 
                title: "Change Password", 
                subtitle: "",
                icon: "Cloud", 
                userInfo: {
                    url: "app://change"
                }
            }

        ]);
```

*I am using:*

**"react-native-quick-actions": "^0.3.13",**

**"react": "16.8.6",**

**"react-native": "0.60.5",**

Comment: do you find a solution for quick actions? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a function for that :

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter, Linking } from 'react-native';

const navigateToShortcutItem = (shortcutItem) => {
  if (shortcutItem) {
    Linking.openURL(`app://${shortcutItem.userInfo.url}`);
  }
};

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('quickActionShortcut', navigateToShortcutItem);
```